# Slick Slider: building a comparison slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am building a comparison slider.

The idea is that I have two sliders next to each other with the same items in each.

I then filter the sliders based on what each is showing. This way you can look through both sliders without ever seeing matching items.

This is what I have so far:

Codepen: https://codepen.io/flinch85/pen/MWaordK

```
$('.slider-1').slick({
  dots: false,
  arrows: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  easing: 'ease'
});

$('.slider-2').slick({
  dots: false,
  arrows: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  easing: 'ease',
  initialSlide: 1
});


 $('.slider-1').on('beforeChange', function () {
     $(this).slick('slickUnfilter');
   var otherIndex =  $('.slider-2 .slick-active').attr('data-slick-index');
   $(this).slick('slickFilter', 'div:not([data-slick-index="'+ otherIndex +'"])');
 });


 $('.slider-2').on('beforeChange', function (event, slick, slides, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
   $(this).slick('slickUnfilter');
   var otherIndex =  $('.slider-1 .slick-active').attr('data-slick-index');
   $(this).slick('slickFilter', 'div:not([data-slick-index="'+ otherIndex +'"])');

 });
```

It works, except that the first time you slide the second slider, it slides back to the same slide. And on moving the opposite slider and returning, it will repeat the same slide on the first move.

I have tried moving the `slickUnfilter` function to `beforeChange` and the `slickFilter` to happen `afterChange`. This works, but messes the animation as the next item only changes after the slide happens.

Answer (score 0):

use this   `otherIndex+1`   inside the beforeChange function

otherindex still refers to current element

`$('.slider-1').on('beforeChange', function () {
     $(this).slick('slickUnfilter');
   var otherIndex =  $('.slider-2 .slick-active').attr('data-slick-index');
   $(this).slick('slickFilter', 'div:not([data-slick-index="'+ otherIndex+1 +'"])');
 });`

https://codepen.io/vkv88/pen/OJygEgK?editors=1010

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, but the example does not solve my issue. I want to never see the same two slide numbers on screen at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have made this like 2 different carousels.
First one is "one image" corousel, second one is "3 image view carousel". And js code to compare them "by active slide".

```
<div class="left-side-sec-lnd-child" id="pc-only-slide">
  <!--Main slider with only ONE main viewed image as active-->
  <!--START------------------------------>
  <div class="slider slider-single">
    <div class="slick-slide"><img data-lazy="img/slide-one.jpg" alt="" ></div>
    <div class="slick-slide"><img data-lazy="img/slide-two.jpg" alt="" ></div>
    <div class="slick-slide"><img data-lazy="img/slide-three.jpg" alt="" ></div>
  </div>
  <!--END==============================-->
</div>
<div class="right-side-sec-lnd-child">
  <div class="inside-bot-sec-lnd"style="width:100%;">
    <p class="sec-lnd-b-header">A journey not to be<br>forgotten</p>
    <!--NAV slider as child with amount of small images-->
    <!--START------------------------------>
    <div class="variable-width slider-nav" style="width:100%;">
       <div class="slick-slide"><img data-lazy="img/slide-one.jpg" alt="" ></div>
       <div class="slick-slide"><img data-lazy="img/slide-two.jpg" alt="" ></div>
       <div class="slick-slide"><img data-lazy="img/slide-three.jpg" alt="" ></div>
    </div>
  <!--END==============================-->
  </div>
 </div>

 //General carousel - big image view
  $('.slider-single').slick({
     slidesToShow: 1,
     slidesToScroll: 1,
     arrows: false,
     fade: true,
     asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
  });
  //This is for carousel what is working as nav for general carousel
  $('.variable-width').slick({
     slidesToShow: 1,
     slidesToScroll: 1,
     asNavFor: '.slider-single',
     dots: false,
     centerMode: true,
     focusOnSelect: true,
     variableWidth: true
  });
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30571426)